# foreach loop is not working on opened pop up

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

For each loop is not working in opened popup while the same collection i can see when I write it on page

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>my cart</title>
</head>
<body>
<% ArrayList cart=(ArrayList)session.getAttribute("Cart"); 
out.println(cart);
//this line is working
%>
<table>
      <tr bgcolor="#EAEAFF">       
   <td><b>Product ID</b></td>   

  </tr>
  <c:forEach items="${cart}" var="current">
        <tr>
           <td><c:out value="${current}"/></td>            
        </tr>
      </c:forEach>      
      </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should post more code, the main page and the popup code would be nice. And use SO markup for codes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see two problems with the code you posted:

**1 -** the case for `cart` is wrong. In the following code you must have `Cart` with a capital C:

```
<c:forEach items="${Cart}" var="current">
```

Also, this code

```
...
<% ArrayList cart=(ArrayList)session.getAttribute("Cart"); 
out.println(cart);
//this line is working
%>
...
<c:forEach items="${cart}" var="current">
```

does not pick up the `cart` variable you created with the scriptlet (if that's what you are thinking). `cart` is a local variable in the servlet generated from your JSP. The tag won't be able to access it).

**2 -** where is the taglib declaration for your `c:forEach` tag? Something like:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

If the server does not recognize the tag as what it is, it will output the thing directly into the response. Your browser won't recognize `<c:forEach>` and will ignore it (i.e. you have it in the source code but it is not displayed on the screen).

Use the following code for your JSP and it should work:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
  <title>my cart</title>
</head>
<body>
<table>
  <tr bgcolor="#EAEAFF">       
    <td><b>Product ID</b></td>   
  </tr>
  <c:forEach items="${Cart}" var="current">
    <tr>
     <td><c:out value="${current}" /></td>            
    </tr>
  </c:forEach>      
 </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<c:forEach items="${sessionScope.cart}" var="current">
```

This should do the trick, you are trying to get a variable that is probably out of the default scope (page).

Comment: No, he has saved it with key `Cart` and is trying to access it with key `cart`. To fix it, he has to save it with key `cart` or to access it with key `Cart`. Besides, the `${}` just scans all scopes for the attribute, not only the page scope.